# IntelliJ "Problems" view shows only few errors

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

IntelliJ "Problems" view shows only few errors.

Any setting to show all the errors? or is there a limit to number of lines displayed in the Problems view that we can increase?

I'm using Community edition.

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot with missing error?

Comment: there are 100+  errors across  multiple projects but the problems view show only around 30 problems.

Comment: Is it possible to define what error is missing?